Dilation of Open Ball to Unit Ball in Complex Plane
Suppose $S=\{z\in \mathbb{C} : |z-a|<r \}$ is an open unit ball in right half plane. Then can we get $c>0$ such that $c. S = \{cz : z\in S \}\subset \{z\in \mathbb{C}: |z-1|<1$?
I tried the follwing way
Since $S$ is in the right half plane, so all $z\in S$ has $Re(z)>0$.
Now $c.S$ consists of the points such that $|\frac{z}{c}-a|<r$ i.e. the points in $c.S$ satisfies $|z-ca|<cr$. To get all points in $|z-ca|<cr$ are inside $|z-1|<1$, the radius $cr$ must be less than 1.Thus the the distance betwwen $ca$ and 1 must be less than 1. After that how to proceed further, I am in trouble.

Find a ball around $0$ with radius $R$ which contains $S$. Set $c=1/R$.
